# Actual long double precision does not agree with std::numeric_limits

Tags: c++, g++, precision, x86-64, long-double

Working on Mac OS X 10.6.2, Intel, with i686-apple-darwin10-g++-4.2.1, and compiling with the -arch x86_64 flag, I just noticed that while...

```
std::numeric_limits<long double>::max_exponent10 = 4932
```

...as is expected, when a long double is actually set to a value with exponent greater than 308, it becomes inf--ie in reality it only has 64bit precision instead of 80bit.

Also, `sizeof()` is showing long doubles to be 16 bytes, which they should be.

Finally, using `<limits.h>` gives the same results as `<limits>`.

Does anyone know where the discrepancy might be?

```
long double x = 1e308, y = 1e309;  
cout << std::numeric_limits<long double>::max_exponent10 << endl;  
cout << x << '\t' << y << endl;  
cout << sizeof(x) << endl;
```

gives

> 4932
>   1e+308 inf
>   16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `1e309` is a literal that gives a double. You need to use a long-double literal `1e309L`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  

Unfortunately, I was only using the literals as a test case, after I noticed this happening with the return values of the pow() function, even with very careful typing.  

Thank god it's not a compiler issue though!

Comment: Yeah, sadly, pow( (long double)2, 1020 ) = 1.12356e+307 and pow( (long double)2, 1030 ) = inf ...any ideas?

Comment: @dmb: There are 3 variants of `pow`. `pow` operates on `double`. You need `powl`.

Comment: Yes! Thanks again, I really appreciate it.  Those trailing L's do everything...  why are they not on cplusplus.com??

Comment: @dmb: cplusplus.com isn't very good. But it's not very bad either, and at least it's easy to search.

Comment: @dmb: In C++, `std::pow` is overloaded, you don't need the separate names such as `powf` and `powl`.  But you do need the header `<cmath>` that provides the overloads, as `<math.h>` may not.

Comment: @dmb cplusplus.com has a lot of incorrect entries. Better use http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow which is maintained by people who understands the standard more